# Is possible migrating a old project (jquery and js) to use webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I have a legacy project, it was built using cdn urls and local scripts (some them are minified).

Everytime I need (manually) minify every file to a better perfomance on frontend.

Is possible use webpack in this case? If there are some others options, will be welcome!!

Comment: It certainly is possible, the question is, is it worth the effort. You don't provide many details how big your code base is. If it's just a couple JS files we're talking about, and you're already using a module loader like RequireJS, I would say it's doable.

Comment: So, this project has at least 2 scripts file per page. I think there are 20 pages. For a better organization I decide develop like a component-based using Singleton Pattern writing only in js and use some features from jquery to manipulate the DOM. Before that strategy, the code have written on single file and all these pages was a bootstrap modal lol. I don't know RequireJS, I will search about it. Thanks

Comment: Don't bother, RequireJS is outdated, I just thought your project might use it

Comment: Humm, that's ok.